# C# creating a new list in a for loop rather than expanding on it

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I'm working in MVC and have a View that looks like this

```
//UPDATED
  @foreach (Site s in sites)
        {

            <tr style="color:black">
                @foreach (var col in ViewBag.OffReportColumns)
                {
                    <th>@col </th>
                }
            </tr>

             <tr style="color:black">
                    @foreach (var cell in ViewBag.OffReportRows)
                    {
                        <td>@cell</td>
                    }
             </tr>

             <tr style="font-size: 20px">
                    @foreach (var cell in ViewBag.OffReportTotal)
                    {
                        <td>@cell</td>
                    }
             </tr>

        }
```

And a controller method that looks like this

```
 List<string> OffReportColumns = new List<string>(7);
 List<List<string>> OffReportRows = new List<List<string>>();
 List<List<string>> OffReportTotal = new List<List<string>>();


            foreach (Site s in sites)
            {

                OffReportColumns.Add(s.Name);
                OffReportColumns.Add("");
                OffReportColumns.Add("");
                OffReportColumns.Add("Average Cost");
                OffReportColumns.Add("");
                OffReportColumns.Add("");
                OffReportColumns.Add("Average Cost With Labour");

                OffReportRows.Add(new List<string>
                {
                    "Parts",
                    "",
                    "",
                    osiPartCost[s.ID].ToString("C2"),
                    "",
                    "",
                    osiPartCost[s.ID].ToString("C2")
                });

                OffReportRows.Add(new List<string>
                {
                    "",
                    "600000 series",
                    osiOpc6[s.ID].ToString("C2"),
                    "",
                    "600000 series",
                    osiOpc6[s.ID].ToString("C2"),
                    ""
                });
                OffReportRows.Add(new List<string>
                {
                     "",
                     "700000 series",
                     osiOpc7[s.ID].ToString("C2"),
                     "",
                     "700000 series",
                     osiOpc7[s.ID].ToString("C2"),
                     ""
                 });
                OffReportRows.Add(new List<string>
                {
                      "",
                      "800000 series",
                      osiOpc8[s.ID].ToString("C2"),
                      "",
                      "800000 series",
                      osiOpc8[s.ID].ToString("C2"),
                      ""
                });
                OffReportRows.Add(new List<string>
                {
                       "Tools",
                       "",
                       "",
                       osiTools[s.ID].ToString("C2"),
                       "",
                       "",
                       osiTools[s.ID].ToString("C2"),

                });
                OffReportRows.Add(new List<string>
                {
                        "",
                        "900000 series",
                        osiOpc9[s.ID].ToString("C2"),
                        "",
                        "900000 series",
                        osiOpc9[s.ID].ToString("C2"),
                        ""
                });
                OffReportRows.Add(new List<string>
                {
                        "",
                        "Other",
                        osiOpco[s.ID].ToString("C2"),
                        "",
                        "Other",
                        osiOpco[s.ID].ToString("C2"),
                        ""
                });
                OffReportRows.Add(new List<string>
                {
                        "Components",
                        "",
                        "",
                        osiCompCost[s.ID].ToString("C2"),
                        "",
                        "",
                        osiLoCompCost[s.ID].ToString("C2")
                });
                OffReportRows.Add(new List<string>
                {
                        "Items",
                        "",
                        "",
                        osiItemCost[s.ID].ToString("C2"),
                        "",
                        "",
                        osiLoItemCost[s.ID].ToString("C2")
                });
                OffReportTotal.Add(new List<string>
                {
                        "Total",
                        "",
                        "",
                        osiTotal[s.ID].ToString("C2"),
                        "",
                        "",
                        osiFltotal[s.ID].ToString("C2")
                });

                ViewBag.OffReportRows = OffReportRows;
                ViewBag.OffReportColumns = OffReportColumns;
                ViewBag.OffReportTotal = OffReportTotal;
            }
```

Here is my sites model

```
public class Site
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string Province { get; set; }
        public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    }
```

I have 5 sites in my "Sites" table. My goal is that I want to create a table for each site. Right Now this is what is happening

[image: Interface]

As you can see the Columns are running right instead of creating them for each table. And you can also see that the "OffReportTotals" don't appear to be there. The problem is that they are all printing near the bottom of the page, so it looks like this

[image: Totals]

I know that it's just making the list longer each time it iterates through the loop and isn't actually creating a new list each time. But how can I make it so instead of extending to the list, it just creates a new list each time it loops through.

Comment: What IDE are you using to develop this application? Visual Studio 2019? Visual Studio Code?

Comment: @Leron_says_get_back_Monica Visual Studio 2019

Comment: you need to improve your data structure first. If you want to do everything inside the loop, consider complex data structure. Something like Sites <= multiple site <= multiple columns

Comment: @Md.SharifulSiddique I don't get why my data structure is that relevant to this. I just am wondering how I can create a new list each time in a for loop without overwriting or expanding on the first list that is created

Comment: @chris, probably we both are saying the same thing. If you want a list of sites where every site has their own list of data rows, column headers and aggregated value, you need to create the list for sites and populate that. In your code you are adding all data rows in the same list.

Comment: @Md.SharifulSiddique I think I am beginning to understand what you mean

Comment: @Md.SharifulSiddique I updated my view. Obviously it doesn't work how it currently is but am I on the right track?

Comment: The loop looks right. If you want separate tables for each site, just bring in the table tag inside the loop. Now you need to figure out how to hold 3 different lists for each site. It would be much easier to declare a view-model and pass the data through the view mode. cheers!